# Python pie chart using matplotlib, rearrange labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Lets say I have the following Pie Chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sizes = [0.988799675982225, 0.009625725741571165, 0.0015745982762038959]
labels = ["Aaaaaa", "Bbbbbbbbbb", "CcCcccCc"]
plt.pie(sizes, labels = labels)
plt.show()
```

We immediately see the overlap of the labels. Is it possible to create a line from the fraction to the label and furthermore, get more distance between them?

Like this, for example:
[image: selfmade labels]

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to achieve this efficiently. Your safest bet is to place the labels separately(imagine having a lot more fragments in a single pie chart). Try this as an alternative:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sizes = [0.988799675982225, 0.009625725741571165, 0.0015745982762038959]
labels = ["Aaaaaa", "Bbbbbbbbbb", "CcCcccCc"]
patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes)
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had that before, but in one plot i actually have many different fragments, therefore the colours are not that distinguishable anymore :/ Therefore I wanted to put the label outside of the pie. I even tried moving some fragments with explode (and until now, I believe that is the best way)

Comment: @mutilis you can easily [specify the colours in hex](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html), giving you plenty of combinations to work with.

Comment: i am sometimes working with many fractions, therefore i wanted to use a gradient, but sadly my advisor would like it more as seen above :) will have to do it like that, if i dont find a suitable answer :( thanks for the help, much appreciated :)